# String replace replacing wrong part

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have an image with a couple of arrows either side to increment/decrement the image filename. Here's the left arrow code:

```
$('#sidebar-b').on("click", "#lar", function() {
    var num = parseInt($('#main-img').attr('src').match(/(\d+)/)[1], 10);
    if (num > 1) {
        $('#main-img').attr('src', $('#main-img').attr('src').replace(/\d+/, function(val) { 
            return parseInt(val)-1
        }));
    } 
});
```

And the right is very similar.

```
$('#sidebar-b').on("click", "#rar", function(){
    var num = parseInt($('#main-img').attr('src').match(/(\d+)/)[1], 10);
    if (num < $('#scroller').children().length) {
        $('#main-img').attr('src',$('#main-img').attr('src').replace(/\d+/, function(val) { 
            return parseInt(val)+1
        })); 
    }
});
```

Works excellent when the images are in "images/" but if they are in "images/h3/" or any directory with a number, every time I click the arrows it simply increments the directory name instead (images/h3/1.jpg, images/h4/1.jpg etc.)

This is obviously no good.

Tried changing the regex, probably be better if it selected characters after the last / or before a period.

Could maybe even use id.lastIndexOf('/')?

I've been coding all day and my brain is just fried at the moment, so I'm going to give my eyes a rest and have a cup of tea.

Hopefully one of you amazing people will point out the obviousness of where I am going wrong.

Currently everything just looks like scrambled digits to me and I can't see the wood for the trees!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need regex in this case:

```
$('#sidebar-b').on("click", "#lar", function() {
    var s = $('#main-img').attr('src') ;
    var slashI = s.lastIndexOf('/'),
        dotI = s.lastIndexOf('.') ;
    var num  = parseInt(s.substring(slashI + 1, dotI)) ;
    if (!isNaN (num)) {
        $('#main-img').attr('src', s.substring(0, slashI + 1) + (num - 1) + s.substring(dotI));
    } 
});
```

Comment: Great solution Holt but negatives are still numbers so `if (!isNaN (num)) {` is still better as `if (num > 1) {`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a positive lookahead based regex. Now this would increments the number which exists only before to the extension.

```
$('#sidebar-b').on("click", "#lar", function(){
var num = parseInt($('#main-img').attr('src').match(/(\d+)(?=\.[^\/.]*$)/)[1], 10);
if (num > 1) {
$('#main-img').attr('src',$('#main-img').attr('src').replace(/\d+(?=\.[^\/.]*$)/,     
function(val) { return parseInt(val)-1}));
} 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Avinash, this does indeed work. I know that regex adds a bit of overhead (probably negligible, but still) also looking at indexof() solutions. Your regex is spot on though! I was slowly going blind trying all the different combinations.

Comment: But I saw regex tag on your question. I think `idexof` won't work if the filename and the digits are dynamic.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm saying that you are correct, but I'm also looking at different solutions out of curiosity for the different methods it can be achieved by. But your answer works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.match` with `RegExp` `/\d+\./`

---

```js
var url = "images/h4/1.jpg";
console.log(parseInt("images/h4/1.jpg".match(/\d+\./), 10));
```